# what kind of technology is node-chat using

Tags: javascript, ajax, chat, comet, websocket

This is the node-chat I'm inquiring about:
http://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat

How are the messages being passed to the server?

websocket comet ajax?

How does it work?

Is what it's using scalable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- it uses [node.js](http://node.js) running as a [specialized http-server](http://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat/blob/master/lib/server.js), reacting via a REST-like API to requests, delivering json.
- the client is a jquery enhanced "website" which [polls its information from the server](http://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat/blob/master/web/nodechat.js) via `jquery.ajax()` (the json-chunks could be fetched via jQuery.getJSON() as well [just normal http fetch]).
- since it is just a little show-off i doubt it is "scalable" in terms of "distribute this like hell over thousands of machines to handle millions of users".

Comment: thanks, just to clarify, it uses ajax to poll the server periodically? I was just surprised by the speed of the updates, so it's not any sort of long polling or anything like that at all.